# Toggle display on element click with PHP (No JavaScript)

Tags: php, html, css, onclick, display

Is it possible to toggle an element display onclick without JavaScript at all?
I am trying to make one button display a popup when it's clicked, but I want that to work, even if the user does not have JavaScript enabled in their browser. Is this possible?

Comment: But `onclick` is javascript or event to other browser scripting lang

Comment: Since PHP is a server sided language you would need to reload the page in order to display the element

Comment: `even if the user does not have JavaScript enabled in their browser` serving users without javascript is fruitless these days